# MathJax issues in Reopen Votes review queue

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen, mathjax

When reviewing Reopen Votes on questions which have been edited, the behaviour of MathJax is a little bit different than on the regular Q&A pages. For example, the side-by-side markdown view shows *rendered* MathJax ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1131808)):

[image]

Note that the same view in the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3058801/revisions) behaves as expected:

[image]

<sub>My original trigger to post this bug was that I got this question as the second item in the review; in that case, the MathJax isn't rendered, and I noticed the different on refreshing the page. I'll have a look at what happens in the other views, but Reopen Votes review items are quite rare on Mathematics Stack Exchange, let alone situations where there are *two* of them, and the second one adds MathJax.</sub>